# Having ULs for foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

Couple of issues here I'm not sure on what the issue is but with how my coding is set up it looks odd in the firebug with how the uls, lis, and h2s are rendered. Any ideas why and also I need some suggestions on how to fix the errors I am getting which is caused by some categories not having child pages. In which case if they don't have child pages I don't want my code to do anything just pass over it.

kansasoutlawwrestling.com/site-map

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($categoriesArray);
echo "</pre>";
if((isset($categoriesArray)) AND ((!empty($categoriesArray))||($categoriesArray !== NULL)))
{
if(count($categoriesArray) <= 0)
{
    echo "There are no content pages on this site!";
}
else
{
    foreach ($categoriesArray as $row)
    {
        echo "<h2>".stripslashes($row['name'])."</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach  ($row['children'] as $row2)
        {
            echo "<li><a href=\"".$row2['link_url']."\">".stripslashes($row2['link_name'])."</a></li>";
            if (count($row2) > 0)
            {
                echo "<ul>";
                foreach ($row2['child_pages'] as $row3)
                {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"".$row3['link_url']."\">".stripslashes($row3['link_name'])."</a></li>";
                }   
                echo "<ul>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
  }
}
else
{
    echo "There are no content pages on this site!";
}
?>
```

EDIT: Any other ideas for me to try?

Comment: I don't understand this: if (count($row2) > 0) . Because you echo $row2['link_url'] this if will never be false (obviously it can be array() but in this case $row2['link_url'] will give a null result)

Comment: This isn't a very clear description of what's wrong. What errors are you getting? When describing an issue, always state what you expect to happen and what actually happens, including any error or warning messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do;

```
if(count($row2['child_pages']) < 1) {
  continue;
}
```

Hope it helps